# Unexpected results from FANN library

Tags: c++, neural-network, fann

Using [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann) library I get unpredictable results. Training file :

```
132 600 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1
// .. the file continues up to 132 rows
```

Amount of training data might not be enough (44 for one desired output) but I have only 3 outputs to distinguish. Implementation :

```
const unsigned int num_input = 600;
const unsigned int num_output = 3;
const unsigned int num_layers = 3;
const unsigned int num_neurons_hidden = 36;
const float desired_error = (const float) 0.0001;
const unsigned int max_epochs = 500000;
const unsigned int epochs_between_reports = 250;

struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input, num_neurons_hidden, num_output);
fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
fann_train_on_file(ann, "traindata.data", max_epochs, epochs_between_reports, desired_error);
```

I input the data on which the network was trained and got :

```
-0.984213
-0.864371
-0.698056

-0.969645
-0.890114
-0.992615

-0.922377
-0.908642
0.383230
```

Answer (score 1):

for output layer **dont use** a symetric activation function
and use a FannTool for training :)